# How to extend getRangeLabel in MatPaginatorIntl?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am total Angular beginner. I see existing code in some application and I would like to add some suffix to standard label of angular material paignator: MatPaginatorIntl. And I must use some parameter which I would evaluate to add such suffix.

I have Angular standard paginator:

```
const rangeLabel = (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => {
    if (length === 0 || pageSize === 0) {
        return `0 of ${length}`;
    }

    length = Math.max(length, 0);

    const startIndex = page * pageSize;
 
    const endIndex = startIndex < length ? Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) : startIndex + pageSize;
 
    return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} of ${length}`;
};

function Paginator(): MatPaginatorIntl {
    const paginatorIntl = new MatPaginatorIntl();

    paginatorIntl.itemsPerPageLabel = 'Elements per page';
    paginatorIntl.nextPageLabel = 'Next page';
    paginatorIntl.previousPageLabel = 'Prev page';
    paginatorIntl.getRangeLabel = rangeLabel ;

    return paginatorIntl;
}

export const arxMatPaginator = Paginator();
```

And I would like to change the label from

```
return `${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} of ${length}`;
```

to:

```
return ${startIndex + 1} - ${endIndex} of ${length}. Results are limited for
  efficiency reasons.
```

but the MatPaginatorIntl has this getRangeLabel three params method:

```
 getRangeLabel: (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number) => string;
```

And I would maybe need something like this to extend the label:

```
getRangeLabel: (page: number, pageSize: number, length: number, boolean: resultsLimited) => string;
```

Or I could provide resultsLimited parameter in other way.. How to implement such paginator ?